# MySQL, I want to Insert, Update, or Delete based on Join result

Tags: mysql

I need to reconcile two systems.  One on the mainframe (`MASTER`) and one on a Windows server (`SLAVE`).  This will be done on a daily basis.

My idea is to download an extract of the mainframe system, build a database table, join this table with the server's table, then issue `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements based on the discrepancies.

It's an enrollment table.  A student can enroll/drop a class; earn a grade; have the professor change the grade.

Example: The `MASTER` system says the kid has the following:

```
MATH B-
BIOLOGY C+
```

and the `SLAVE` system says:

```
MATH A
ECONOMICS C
```

Is there a query that will join two tables and issue an `INSERT` on BIOLOGY, an `UPDATE` on MATH's grade, and a `DELETE` on ECONOMICS?

I know how to do this with a program that will digest the results of the `JOIN`, but I wanted to know if MySQL could do this a bit more simply.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication.html

Comment: Check out the link provided by @eggyal.  Replication is probably your best bet here. It takes some learning to set up, but the power of replication is worth the investment of time.

Comment: Aside from replication (go for it!), if you only want / need to bring the other database up to speed once a day, you could also replay a servers binlog with `mysqlbinlog` on another database.

Comment: @Wrikken: Isn't that essentially all that replication does?

Comment: @eggyal: nope, part of it, but hardly all. Interesting differences for this case are mainly: (a) databases don't need to be able to talk to each other directly or configure replication users (i.e.:  just pomp over the logs in the manner you see fit & run `mysqlbinlog ... | mysql` so (b) updating the other database is more easily scheduled on desirable hours (when there's less then normal traffic for instance, not impossible in normal replication) (c) it _does_ make it harder to detect possible errors.

Comment: I need to clarify what's going on.

The mainframe data is not in a database.  The only link between the mainframe and the application server is via FTP.  Thus, I have to create an extract file of mainframe data.

This extracted data will be fed into the application server's database as a newly created table.  Call it MASTER_TABLE.  The application server's table of students, call it SLAVE_TABLE, has more fields than I'm concerned with.  Where these tables DO overlap, is my concern.

Replication will not work, because the tables are different.  I only want to act on changes in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL across servers is not going to work for you.

If you have a large database, look into MySQL's Replication feature.

If you have a small database (300MB or less), just write a shell script that:

- does mysqldump daily (*without gzip compression*) on the master
- then rsync's it over to the slave (*this will gzip it*)
- if rsync is configured correctly and overwrites yesterday's *.sql file then only a couple hundred KB of network traffic will be needed to keep two 300MB sql files in sync
- finally import the sql file to the slave

Comment: My appologies, not using SQL across servers.  I'm going to extract all the data on the mainframe down to the Windows server.  The mainframe is not running MySQL.  The extracted data will be used to create a MySQL file.

Comment: @user2383487: What RDBMS is in use on the "mainframe" ?

Comment: If the master and slave have different software then nothing is going to work well. That's a terrible idea. The master and slave need to be running the _same version_ of the _same software_.